# Firestore suddenly has a huge trigger delay

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We are running an application on Firestore and got a simple trigger that when order's details are created or updated some of it's information should be rewritten in the parent order collection.

The function for this got following code

```
export const updateOrderDetails = functions
  .region(FUNCTION_REGION)
  .firestore.document("orders/{orderId}/details/pickupAndDropoff")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    return await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("orders")
      .doc(context.params.orderId)
      .set({ pickupAndDropoff: change.after.data() }, { merge: true });
  });
```

It was work fine before, but now at random about every third of its executions is delayed. Sometimes by few minutes. In Cloud Function logs we see normal execution times <200ms, so it seems the trigger runs after a huge pause.

What's worse from time to time our `change.after.data()` is undefined, but we never delete anything - it's just updates and creates.

It was working fine, we did not changed nothing since last week, but now it started to have this unexpected delays. We've also checked the firebase status, but there are no malfunctions in firebase functions service. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Do you have a number for the slower Functions, and when this happens? Is it in the initial trigger? Or in the processing? Could it be cold starts, for example because one of the other Functions is not yet finished, so GCF needs to spin up a new instance?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand that cold start would be seen in a functions log saying it took 3000ms instead of 100ms, right? We don't have that problem. We are running just this function, we are doing this once a few seconds and after 3-4 cycles it gets stuck and delayed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen today all works fine again, after ~30 hours of this problem persistence. We changed nothing. Do you think it's possible that it was an infrastructure problem? We've seen no information about outages in the cloud functions service.

Comment: I haven't heard anything about an outage (they're extremely rare on Firestore), and also haven't seen similar reports. But if you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, they *might* be able to check. --- A common cause of performance disappearing over time is also when you first hit a surge in load, as Firestore needs time to ramp up. See the docs on this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic).

Comment: Okay, I've made a support ticket, but in the meantime will be happy to hear of someone encountered similar problem and what was the reason of it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked in my last comment too? Could that be what you're hitting?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah, but at this point there is no traffic. We are producing the software so the only people using it are our developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Frank van Puffelen suggestion we've sent this question directly to Firebase support and after their internal investigation we've got the reply from an engineering team that it was in fact an infrastructure malfunction.

The reply I got from them was:

> I escalated the issue to recover more information. So far it appears that there was an issue with pub/sub delivering and creating the event. The Firestore team is also communicating with the pub/sub team to investigate the issue and prevent future incidents.

It seems that the best way to deal with such problems is to quickly write directly to Firebase support team, because as they mentioned in the automatic reply I got after sending a support ticket:

> For Firebase outages not listed on the status dashboard, we'll respond within 4 hours.

which seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be due to the monotonically increasing **orderId** as the parameter passed here:

```
...
.collection("orders")
  .doc(context.params.orderId)
...
```

If you can check once if the **orderId** passed here is monotonically increasing with each request? It can lead to **hotspots** which impacts **latency**.

To explain, I think the write rate must be changing at different day's and time's - *as the user traffic using the application or load testing requests changes* - which is creating the unexpected kind of behaviour. At **low write rate**, the requests are working as expected most of the time. At **high write rate**, the requests are facing hotspot situation in the firestore as mentioned in the firestore documentation resulting in delays (latency issue).

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#indexes) is the relevant link to firestore best practices documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by monotonically increasing? In our case orderId is the unique identifier generated by firebase, it's not an auto incremented value. Also we are not having any traffic as we were just testing it in Firestore console changing one document at the time every 10-15 seconds still getting the delays.

Comment: Monotonically increasing means sequential increase like order1, order2 etc. As you said, if the orderid is unique and random, the cloud function is showing < 200ms execution time, cloud functions are not malfunctioning, then you might be looking at wrong place to fix an issue. Can you tell how you are testing the cloud function? Let's hit all possible ends to find a solution. If the function caller service/dependency is responsible for creating delay's, we can look forward to fix that to solve the problem.